# Ramanujan's infinite sum for pi

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, ramanujan

Ramanujan's famous pi formula states that

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{99^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(4k)!}{k!^4}\frac{26390k+1103}{396^{4k}}
\end{equation}

How can one prove this? If the proof is too long for this site, you can reference any article containing the proof.

Comment: I added some tags. I also found, after searching for "Ramanujan Sato series proof" an AMM article _Ramanujan's Series for 1/π: A Survey_ https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2009.11920975 ([pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/monthly567-587.pdf)), which references J. M. Borwein and P. B. Borwein, _Pi and the AGM; A Study in Analytic Number Theory and Computational Complexity_, Wiley, New York, 1987 ([publisher page](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Pi+and+the+AGM%3A+A+Study+in+Analytic+Number+Theory+and+Computational+Complexity-p-9780471315155). as containing the first proofs.

Comment: This should also help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series

Comment: Borwein, J. M.; Borwein, P. B.; Bailey, D. H. (1989). "Ramanujan, modular equations, and approximations to pi; Or how to compute one billion digits of pi" ([PDF](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/amm_supplements/Monthly_Reference_1.pdf)). Amer. Math. Monthly. 96 (3): 201–219. https://doi.org/10.1080%2F00029890.1989.11972169 might be better.

Comment: All the articles were good.